# Convert Output<string> to string for AssumeRolePolicy

Tags: f#, pulumi

I am trying to get my head around pulumi using F# but I am unable to understand how to use Output values issued from one resource eventually into another resource. Here my specific case :

```
let infra() =

        let adminsName = "admins"
        let current =
            Output.Create<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<GetCallerIdentityResult>>(GetCallerIdentity.InvokeAsync()).Apply<GetCallerIdentityResult>(fun x->
                x
                |> Async.AwaitTask
                |> Async.RunSynchronously
            )

        let adminRoleName = sprintf "%s-eksClusterAdmin" adminsName

        let adminRolePolicy =
            current.Apply(fun id ->
                @"{
                  ""Version"": ""2012-10-17"",
                  ""Statement"": [
                    {
                      ""Action"": ""sts:AssumeRole"",
                      ""Principal"": {
                        ""AWS"": ""arn:aws:iam::" + id.AccountId + @":root""
                      },
                      ""Effect"": ""Allow"",
                      ""Sid"": """"
                    }
                  ]
                }"
            )


        let adminsIamRole =
            Role (adminRoleName,
                RoleArgs(AssumeRolePolicy= (adminRolePolicy.Apply(fun x -> x)))
            )
```

I have been heavily inspired by the following walkthrough that I am trying to port to f#

https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/crosswalk/kubernetes/identity/#create-an-iam-role-for-admins

Currently building the project tells me :

```
iam.fs(47,45): error FS0001: The type 'Output<string>' is not compatible with the type 'Input<string>'
iam.fs(47,44): error FS0193: Type constraint mismatch. The type     'Output<string>'    is not compatible with type    'Input<string>'
```

How can  I cast Output into Input with pulumi ?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this, but am trying to reproduce the compiler error. What Amazon packages and namespaces are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a helper function `io` to convert an output to an input

```
AssumeRolePolicy = io adminRolePolicy
```

You need to reference the `Pulumi.FSharp` NuGet package.

See [`io` source](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/blob/master/sdk/dotnet/Pulumi.FSharp/Library.fs#L16) and [a usage example](https://github.com/pulumi/examples/blob/master/aws-fs-s3-folder/Program.fs#L28).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I just found it out.  I'll mark you as answer! 
I thank you for the link I was struggling with the documentation on pulumi site and it is not always obvious.

Comment: By the way thanks for your post in f# advent calendar, this led me to trying out pulumi for my pet project...

Comment: Great! Feel free to ping me on https://slack.pulumi.com/ or on twitter, happy to help another F#-er.